# How to shorten an xpath element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

How can I shorten this element (xpath) to be located.

/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div[4]/ul/li[2]/p[1]/span/text()

HTML:

```
<li class="faq-answer" style="display: list-item;">
    <p style="line-height: normal;">
        <span style="color: #222222; font-family: calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt;">**technology platform layer which provides the facility** </span>
    </p>
</li>
```

The text above that I want to locate is stored in a table: /html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div[4]/ul/li[2]/p[1]/span/text()

```
<ul class="faq">
    <li class="faq-question">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i> What company?
    </li>
    <li class="faq-answer" style="display: list-item;">
        <p style="line-height: normal;">
            <span style="color: #222222; font-family: calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt;" technology platform layer which provides the facility .</span>
        </p>
```

Comment: share the html of the element

Comment: <span style="color: #222222; font-family: calibri, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt;">technology platform layer which provides the facility f</span>

Comment: You can edit your question with the html of the table(with children), that gives us the option to provide the right answer.

Comment: body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > ul > li:nth-child(2) (cssSelector)

Comment: We need the html from your browser dev tools, without that we are help less in this case.

Comment: Hi Catia, please use the dev tools to INSPECT the dom of the html in question and copy the surrounding html & elements, (even a screen shot of this would help). So that we can help you identify the correct or better locator to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to determine if the locator is unique because we can't see the rest of the page but given the HTML posted, try the CSS selector

```
li.faq-answer > p > span
```

I'm guessing this is going to return more than one element but the element that you want will be in there.

If you want to find the answer to a particular FAQ question, you can use the XPath below and insert the question into the locator

```
//li[contains(.,'What company?')]//following::span[1]
```

and this would return, " technology platform layer which provides the facility .", given your HTML.